# How do I reference 2 aliases and compare them in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, db2

I have this

```
RECORD                               ITEMS      ITEMSTOTAL
------------------------------------ ---------- ----------
ababababaa                                    0          1
ababababab                                    0          0
ababababac                                    0          1
ababababad                                    1          1
ababababae                                    0          2
```

but I need this output when ITEMS=ITEMSTOTAL

```
RECORD                               
------------------------------------ 
ababababab
ababababad
```

Currently I'm using this query for the first result, but I don't know how to get the second output, Maybe this sounds obvious but I can't find the answer :(

```
SELECT RECORD, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 WHERE SOMETHING=X) AS ITEMS,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2 WHERE SOMETHING2=Y) AS ITEMSTOTAL
FROM RECORDS_TABLE
WHERE DELETED=0
--and ITEMS.count = ITEMSTOTAL.count <-- tried something like this but it doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a subquery and apply the `where` criteria to the outer query.

```
select * 
from (
   your query here
) t
where items = itemstotal
```

I assume that isn't your actual query btw.  `where` comes after `from`.  Also, those `count` statements would return the same values.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. Thank you very much, you saved my life!

Comment: Yeah I fix the query too, sorry I was modifying it to have it more easy to understand.